# Unmatched arguments from index 2 while trying to generate java wrapper class web3j

Tags: truffle, web3j

I am trying to create wrapper class for my smart contract using standard command

```
web3j truffle generate build\contracts\PKCoin.json -o src\main\java\ -p com.example.polygontestapp
```

but keep getting error

```
Unmatched arguments from index 2: 'build\contracts\PKCoin.json', '-o', 'src\main\java\', '-p', 'com.example.polygontestapp'
Did you mean: tests or truffle or solidity?
```

if i replace places for generate and truffle in command then i get another error

```
Missing required option '--truffle-json=<jsonFileLocation>'
```

so whatever i do i get some error,
I am using web3j cli 1.4.1 version
and web3j 4.8.9 version before that i was using version 3.6.0 and it worked fine but i had to update version,
my platform is android
**EDIT: screenshot of my project structure in android studio:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok syntax is changed and nowhere in the documentation is it stated,so the new sintax is

```
web3j generate truffle --truffle-json path/to/yourJson.json --outputDir path/where/to/generate -p com.example.dapp
```

so in my case it would be like this

```
web3j generate truffle  --truffle-json build\contracts\NFTMarketPlace.json --outputDir src\main\java\ -p com.example.polygontestapp
```